# Can I release an iCloud user name by changing the user ID?

Tags: icloud, email, apple-id

I have a primary iCloud account which I use daily, and a second, legacy account which was created many years ago using a legacy `old.name@me.com` domain. I have full access to both accounts.

I can also log into the legacy account using `old.name@icloud.com` – even though I never allocated this `@icloud` identity myself, Apple appears to have done it for me. I would like to use `old.name@icloud.com` as an email address with my *primary* iCloud account (which uses a non-iCloud domain as its user ID, and doesn't yet have iCloud email activated). I can't do this currently, because this `@icloud` email address is allocated to my old account.

If I change the username associated with my legacy account from `old.name@me.com` to `old.name@somewhere.else.com`, will that release `old.name@icloud.com` so I can use it with my primary account? I've read that if I delete the old account, the user ID can never be reused, so I'm holding off doing that, though there are no purchases or other information associated with the old account that I need to preserve. I'm aware that iCloud accounts cannot be merged.

Comment: It depends on the internal implementation of the account management system. If they use the email as a unique id, it may not be released for a certain amount of time after changing. Even if it's released, you have no control over when it will be released.

Comment: No definitive answer yet, just to note that after changing the legacy old.name@me.com Apple ID the associated old.name@icloud.com address is not available after three days.

Comment: Just to note that old.name@icloud.com is not available after over 30 days.